# Count of total value and count of individual value

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, window-functions

I have a table like:

| Id | type | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | coach | 1.0 |
| 2 | coach | True |
| 3 | client | NULL |
| 4 | coach | False |
| 5 | client | NULL |
| 6 | coach | False |
| 7 | client | NULL |
| 8 | coach | True |
| 9 | coach | 1.0 |
| 10 | client | NULL |

I want to:

- create a column where coach status is active when value is 1.0 and True else status should be inactive
- add count of active and inactive values in another column and and total coach count as another column

Here's the expected output:

| Id | type | Status | totalcount | status count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | coach | Active | 6 | 4 |
| 2 | coach | Active | 6 | 4 |
| 4 | coach | Inactive | 6 | 2 |
| 6 | coach | Inactive | 6 | 2 |
| 8 | coach | Active | 6 | 4 |
| 9 | coach | Active | 6 | 4 |

I tried this code

```
Select id,
       (case when status in (1.0,True) 
             then 'Active' 
             else 'Inactive' 
        end) as Status 
from table 
Where type ='Coach'
```

But unable to add count of active and inactive and total coach.

Comment: what's the datatype of status column ? provvaly you should put the values in quotations like  `case when status in ('1.0','True') ....`

Comment: It is string only,  just gave demo

Comment: Expected results would be useful.

Comment: edit your question and provide desired output for your given sample input data

Comment: I have provided expected output

Comment: The problem of your expected output is that there's no Inactive person among coaches. Check the correctness of your samples. @Shivam

Answer (score 1):

Try the following combination of case expressions coupled with a windowed count:

```
select id, type, 
  case when status in ('1.0','True') then 'Active' else 'Inactive' end as Status,
  Count(*) over() TotalCount,
  Count(*) over(partition by case when status in ('1.0','True') then 1 end) StatusCount
from t
where type='coach'
order by Id;
```